# is there have any way to use a Virtual numpad?

Tags: add-on

I want to press the Q KEY to show the Virtual numpad. and then use left mouse to select the view.just like press the numpad keys.

is there have any way to do like this? or have any addons to do ?

Comment: which "Virtual numpad" are you talking about? Is it a software present on your pc/mac?

Comment: You can Emulate numpad in File > User Preferences > Emulate Numpad. Then you can use 1-9 and 0 as numpad. Or download a numpad emulator that lets you set the "Q" key to pop up. This one lets you set up the numpad emulator for any "F#" key (PC): http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpad-emulator/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the pie menus addon, one of the pie menus it adds is the view menu which is attached to <kbd>Q</kbd>.

[image]